# Razor and Javascript code together

Tags: javascript, razor

I am newcomer in asp.net mvc. How can i write javascript code in razor?

```
@foreach (var player in ViewBag.Players) 
    {
        <script>
              team.member=@player.Name;
        </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the razor variable within  single quote-

```
team.member='@player.Name';
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it such simple?

Comment: Worth adding to take the `<script>` element outside of the Razor loop so you won't end up with multiple redundant `<script>` tags that could fit into one.